# How to pass xml to Asp.net Web Api 2 Get function

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient

Just been stuck here for long time now. Thought someone might be able to put me in right direction. I have created a ASP.NET Web API 2 application. There is one function which will return all ships. Now I want to receive an xml inside my controller function. How can I achieve that. Below is my HttpClient calling code which is giving me Bad Request error. Can someone guide me in right direction to how to pass xml to Web api function.

Routing

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Controller Action

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSummaryFunction(string id)
        {
            return Ok(id);
        }
```

Client Code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53633/");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            string testXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SummaryRQ  xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.WebAPI.Controllers\" Version=\"1.00\" Target=\"Test\"><POS><Source Login=\"test\" Password=\"test\"></Source></POS></SummaryRQ>";

            var url = "api/summaryfunction/" + testXml;

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

At minimum you are going to need to pass the `testXml` string to the `Uri.EscapeDataString` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You may also run into some issues if your Xml is too big.  How big is too big depends a lot on the infrastructure that exists between your client and server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but Uri.EscapeDataString didn't work. Infact I tried very simple xml with <test>test</test> and that failed with Bad Request error as well. Not sure how to pass xml here.

Comment: @Leo You need to show what your Controller action method signature is and also your routing.

Comment: @Leo  Is you controller called `SummaryFunctionController` ? And do you really want that entire XML as the value of the `id` parameter?

Comment: @LEo Normally you would pass the XML in the body of a POST or a PUT.  In theory there is nothing wrong with putting it as a parameter of the URI though.

Comment: Yes in fact I need to pass XML in both get and post. XML contains extensive information for api controller function.